# Odoo possibility to track changes on compute field

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo, odoo-10

I have model A with compute field b (it depends on field c and field d values).

```
b = fields.Float(compute='_compute_field')
```

My task is every month **compare past and current month field b values and get differences**. For example I want to compare 2018-04-01 field b value with 2018-05-01 field b value. Firstly I was thinking to store compute value in database. But the problem is that I can't do that (store=True) because if I store field b value in database I always got 0 value on field b.

What can be other **alternatives to track or store compute field values** that I can compare the differences depend on time (date).

Comment: Check the alternative I have written into my answer. Let me know if I understood badly what you want to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare the values month per month I would run an **automated (scheduled) task** every month. Then, I would create a new record with the new value for the field `b` in the task method. So you would have a history of values in this way, one a month.

Therefore, my recommendation is that you should create a normal field without the `compute` attribute:

```
b = fields.Float()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I am thinking  to use ir.cron model for calling my method which will counting new value of field b. Then compare it with old field b value and the difference write into dictionary.

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer was useful please vote it or mark it as the correct answer. Thanks